# Share photo - Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I`m trying to share a photo on facebook but the request always returns access granted NO.

Why?

Here is the code:

```
 ACAccountStore *facebookaccount = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *facebookaccountType = [facebookaccount accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSDictionary *options = @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"*******", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream"], ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends };
    [facebookaccount requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookaccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) { // always returns NO

}}
```